# Spark cassandra sqlcontext with unix epoch timestamp column

Tags: apache-spark

I have Cassandra table with unix epoch timestamp column (value e.g 1599613045). I would like to use spark sqlcontext to select from this table from date to date based on this unix epoch timestamp column. I intend to convert from date, to date input into epoch timestamp and compare (>= & <=) with table epoch ts column. Is it possible ? Any suggestion ? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below approach,

Let's consider cassandra is running on localhost:9042

keyspace-->mykeyspace

tabe-->mytable

columnName-->timestamp

spark-scala code:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   // create SparkSession
  val spark=SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

 //Read table from cassandra, spark-cassandra connector should be added to  classpath
 spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
 spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")

  var cassandraDF = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(Map("keyspace" -> "mykeyspace", "table" -> "mytable")).load()
  
 //select timestamp column
cassandraDF=cassandraDF.select('timestamp)
cassandraDF.show(false)

// let's consider following as the output

+----------+
| timestamp|
+----------+
|1576089000|
|1575916200|
|1590258600|
|1591900200|
+----------+

// To convert the above output to spark's default date format yyyy-MM-dd
val outDF=cassandraDF.withColumn("date",to_date(from_unixtime('timestamp)))
outDF.show(false)

+----------+----------+
| timestamp|      date|
+----------+----------+
|1576089000|2019-12-12|
|1575916200|2019-12-10|
|1590258600|2020-05-24|
|1591900200|2020-06-12|
+----------+----------+

// You can proceed with next steps from here
```